# Error using mklink to create a 'virtual' folder

Tags: windows, mklink

I am trying to use mklink so that when accessing c:\Audio it redirects to e:\Audio

I have tried

```
mklink /D c:\Audio e:\Audio
```

Which creates a what looks like a shortcut folder in c:\Audio but if I click on it or try and access it, I get this error:

```
The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using the absolute path for the Target location, eg `C:\my\path` vs just `path` if you were already in `C:\my`? I had this problem on one and only one folder and switching the Target from relative to absolute path fixed it. Strangely, I could use relative path for other target directories in the same parent directory without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does E:\Audio exist at the time you are accessing C:\Audio? You need network connectivity and proper filesystem permissions for the original location to be able to use a symbolic link.
When I ran mklink, I had to do it in an elevated command prompt. Is it possible your prompt was not elevated at the time it made the symbolic link?

Comment: Hi, yes, it does exist. It is not a network drive, it is a physical hard drive on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Rename (or delete) C:\Audio before you run the command, otherwise it thinks you're trying to create a virtual link inside c:\audio, instead of making c:\audio a virtual directory.

Comment: I have tried to do it with no c:\Audio and it still doesn't work. I see it create what looks like a shortcut folder, but when I click on the folder I get the above error